# access local network router page remotely through SSH

Tags: networking, apache-2.4

I'm trying to access my router page remotely through apache.

I've installed apache with proxy-pass module

httpd.conf file

```
ServerName localhost
Listen *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location /someurl >
        # Password protection omitted for brevity
        ProxyPass http://192.168.10.0
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.10.0
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to reach this page http://192.168.10.0 remotely.

it's working but when I browse http://myipaddress/someurl

I get 503 Service Unavailable, I tried to change the local IP to google website but it redirects me to google website instead of showing it within my IP address.

I really don't know where the problem is. what i'm trying to do is reaching router page remotely to open some port.

### UPDATE

when I've changed the IP address to 192.168.10.1 its keep connecting and redirect me to 192.168.10.1.

I've changed HTTP protocol to https but I get 500 Internal Server Error

### UPDATE 2

When I call curl 192.168.10.1 from my terminal I get:

```
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.7</center>
</body>
</html>
```

but not on my browser.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the IP is 192.168.10.0?  Valid IPs should end in a 1 or 255.

The 503 means that Apache cannot find the server you're trying to connect to.

Comment: I've tried with 192.168.10.1 but its keep connecting, I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Is the Apache host on the same network?  What is the IP you use to reach the router?  Is the router configured to use http or https?

Comment: I've made an update based on your answer.

Comment: What type of device is the router?  A consumer machine, PFSense, ?

Comment: its not about the router, its about accessing local IP address remotely

Comment: So your Apache host is public facing?  To pin down the cause it helps to know the network layout.  If Apache is on an external server (e.g. Amazon) outside of the network where the router is located it will not work.

Comment: no, it's not. apache on the same network. the problem now is apache redirect me to router page instead of showing the content of router page.

Comment: Please check out my update.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer indicates your question was ambiguous-you stated a goal that had no relationship with what you were trying to accomplish-

When seeking help it is important to state details of what you are hoping to accomplish-thoroughly.  At this point it still isn’t clear what you are trying to actually do.

Comment: I mentioned more than once that I was trying to reach router page remotely.

Comment: apache was one of the available solutions but I got this issue when I tried to implement.

Comment: You didn’t say how you were trying to accomplish this or what remotely meant.  Remotely could mean via VPN, forwarded ports in a firewall to an internal host-and much more.  You didn’t provide any detail on where the host with Apache was located relative to your router.

Comment: excuse my brevity, I'm not familiar with servers.

Comment: Just keep it in mind in the future-those details also allow those more experienced to warm you if what you’re trying to accomplish is dangerous (exposing your router’s web interface to the internet is VERY dangerous!)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and follow up the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by making proxy-using-ssh-tunnel which its what I wanted from the beginning.

I wanted to reach router page remotely. so, I called `ssh -D 8080 username@sshd_server` from my client terminal and then in firefox I've added socks5 as following: localhost:8080